# integration over general measure space (proposition 9, chapter 18.2 in Royden)

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I don't understand how "$\mu(X_\infty) \le \int_X f d\mu < \infty$" proves that $f$ is finite a.e. on $X$. I think that this just shows $\mu(X_\infty) < \infty$.

I also don't understand the proof for $\sigma$-finite. By Chebychev's inequality,
$\mu(X_n) \le n \cdot \int_X fd\mu < \infty$. But what if $n = \infty$? I think that the inequality does not hold in this case.

I guess $E_n = X_n$ or $X_n \setminus [\cup_{k=1}^{n-1}X_k]$, right?

I appreciate if you elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the proof that $f$ is finite a.e. is incomplete. We really want to show that $\mu(X_\infty) = 0$, not just that $\mu(X_\infty)<\infty$. Notice that
$$
X_\infty = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{x\in X : f(x) \ge n\},
$$
and observe that $f(x) \ge n$ for each natural number $n$ and each $x\in X_\infty$. If $\mu(X_\infty) > 0$, then
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu \ge \int_{X_\infty}f\,d\mu \ge \int_{X_\infty} n\,d\mu 
 = n\cdot\mu(X_\infty) > 0.
$$
Thus $\int_X f\,d\mu = \infty$, a contradiction of what we assumed that $\int_X f\,d\mu < \infty$.

For the second question about the use of Chebychev's inequality, note that Royden says "Let $n$ be a natural number." Thus, $n$ cannot be $\infty$, which is not a natural number.

---

P.S. Be careful with Royden's book. There are *a lot* of typos or outright errors in it. I would recommend you read it with a copy of the errata next to you.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I am confused about the second answer. We often denote $\cup_{n=1}^\infty$ by $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. If $n$ does not represent $\infty$, how can we justify the equality?

Comment: @Daeseon: You have some confusion about what that notation means. The set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is the set of $x$ for which there is a natural number $n$ such that $x\in E_n$. It does not include a set "$E_\infty$."